# Add product and/or coupon to cart via link (query string) is not working

Tags: cart, coupon, addtocart

As described on Magento's website: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/adding_a_product_to_the_cart_via_querystring

Background: Performed an upgrade from CE 1.7 to 1.9.0.1. Everything else seems to be working fine after following standard procedures (http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-upgrading).

Tried to setup a few links that takes the user to the shopping cart and automatically adds the product to cart. Nothing outside of that; our old methods (e.g. www.website.com/checkout/cart/add?product=8&qty=1&coupon=save25) have stopped working and the user is redirected to an empty cart. I'm not even sure how to troubleshoot this problem. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The add to cart link should include the valid form key.

Comment: Wow! I had never even heard of this mythical "form key" until you mentioned. Learn something new everyday I suppose. Found a link on how to add without form key: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153691/magento-add-a-product-to-the-cart-via-query-string-without-form-key-parameter

Comment: if the answer was helpful, please accept and vote it :)

Comment: Question: That valid form key cannot be obtained unless you are on the site itself, correct? My company has been using these links in email campaigns where they promote the product in the email and the link they provide takes the user to a pre-populated cart. It seems like their may not be a way to do this going forward.